# Matlab rat function in C language

Tags: c, matlab, rational-numbers

Do you know how to make a rational approximation of a decimal number in C (similar to **rat** Matlab function)?

**Update**

If we want a P/Q approximation of a double number *number*, a quick fix could be:

```
int factor=1000000;
P=floor(number*factor);
Q=factor;
```

The error is less than (number/factor), which is negligible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations) can be used to calculate rational approximations to real numbers that are optimal in a sense. That way with the input 0.33333333  you have a chance of obtaining 1/3 rather than 3333/10000.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same as you have done in your update, but then check for the highest common factor between the top and bottom and simplify. For example, `0.5` would go to `500000/1000000` doing it your method. They share a common factor of `500000` so you can divide both top and bottom by that to get `1/2`. Google has a lot of examples of hcf functions , such as [this one](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/data_structures/c/gcd/gcd.c) (Edit: And [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) impressive list).